# How I can get all the string characters after the last characters of "/"?

Tags: powershell

I have this variable inside PowerShell, `/sites/testprojectsite/SitePages`. Now how can I extract all the characters from the last `/` till the end, which is `sitePages` in my case?

Comment: @Luuk i do not have a file

Comment: it works on string too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to get that.

One might be

```
$var = "/sites/testprojectsite/SitePages"
$leaf = $var -split "/" | Select-Object -Last 1
$leaf
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6UssUjBVkFJvzizJLVYH4hLCorys1KTS0AC@sFAIiAxPbVYiUslJzUxDagUrEO3uCAnswSoTUmhRiE4NQeoXtc/CaRNQTcnsbhEwRCi/v9/AA).

Answer (score 0):

You also have the [`string.split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) method which returns an array. With any array, an index of `[-1]` returns the last element:

```
$path = '/sites/testprojectsite/SitePages'
$path.Split('/')[-1]
```

```
PS > $path = '/sites/testprojectsite/SitePages'
PS >
PS > $path.Split('/')[-1]
SitePages
PS >
```

Answer (score -1):

It even works on a Mac, with PowerShell installed

```
Last login: Tue Mar 21 14:28:38 2023
luuk@mini ~ % pwsh
PowerShell 7.3.3
PS /Users/luuk> $x="/sites/testprojectsite/SitePages"
PS /Users/luuk> Split-Path $x -leaf
SitePages
PS /Users/luuk>
```